# Google Forms to Outputting to a Google Docs file. How can I get the Google Docs file to open automatically?

Tags: forms, documentation

Can anyone suggest a script to open a Google Docs file after its creation by Google Forms? I can access the file via Drive but would like it open without having to search for it.

I don't have enough scripting experience to create the code.